# Apply transducer to stream of event callbacks

Tags: clojurescript

I'm writing some clojurescript which is doing some logs processing. I'm wrapping a Javascript library that gives me a callback whenever a new log entry arrives, i.e.

```
(.on my-logs-source "log-entry" handle-log-event)
```

I'd like to perform some simple aggregation on these events using something like clojure's `partition-by` function, which returns a transducer, and get a vector of the results. What is the idiomatic way to transform my stream of event callbacks into something that I can apply a transducer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clojure.async - its channels optionally accept transducers when constructed.

The example below illustrates how you can  achieve your goal.

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as async])

(def ch (async/chan 1 (partition-by odd?)))

(def callback (fn [n] (async/put! ch n)))

(async/go-loop []
  (when-some [v (async/<! ch)]
    (println "Got" v)
    (recur)))

(callback 1)
(callback 1)
(callback 2)
(callback 2)
(callback 3)
(callback 4)
```

The code above will create a channel with a transducer. Your callback function will send all values received to that channel. The go block will consume values from the channel as they become available. The values consumed from the channel are the results produced by the transducer.

For the example REPL session above the console output from your go block will be following:

```
Got [1 1]
Got [2 2]
Got [3]
```

Now when you close the channel:

```
(async/close! ch)
```

the remaining data will be "flushed" from your transducer:

```
Got [4]
```